# MySQL Unique Identifiers on Column Names of UNION Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two different tables that share an 'is_featured' column. I need to select all content that is checked 'is_featured' and sort the results by 'date_display' desc.

```
            PHOTOS

            item_name  |  date_display  |  is_featured
            photo1     |  01-02-13      |  yes
            photo2     |  02-12-13      |  yes
            photo6     |  06-24-12      |  no
            photo23    |  09-24-12      |  no

            VIDEOS

            item_name  |  date_display  |  is_featured
            video5     |  01-14-13      |  no
            video10    |  03-09-13      |  no
            video30    |  03-21-13      |  yes
            video17    |  11-14-12      |  yes


            DESIRED RESULTS - All FEATURED CONTENT Sorted by Date DESC

            item_name  |  date_display  |  is_featured
            video30    |  03-21-13      |  yes
            photo2     |  02-12-13      |  yes
            photo1     |  01-02-13      |  yes
            video17    |  11-14-12      |  yes
```

I'm able to get my desired result with this UNION query:

```
            SELECT *
            FROM (SELECT item_name, date_display
            FROM photos
            WHERE is_featured='yes'
            UNION
            SELECT item_name, date_display
            FROM videos
            WHERE is_featured='yes'
            ) x
            ORDER BY date_display DESC
```

What I need now is to be able to add unique identifiers to the item_names of each table. For examples: photos.item_name and videos.item_name.

Is that possible with the query I have?

I ultimately need to do something like the following:
If (item_name is from Photos table) { do this }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
...
FROM (SELECT item_name, date_display, 'photo' AS media_type
    FROM photos...
```

and similarly for the video subquery. This will create a column media_type in your result set that is 'photo' for the photos, and 'video' for the videos.

Your result set would look like this:

```
        item_name  |  date_display  |  media_type
        video30    |  03-21-13      |  video
        photo2     |  02-12-13      |  photo
        photo1     |  01-02-13      |  photo
        video17    |  11-14-12      |  video
```

Exactly how you check that value depends on how you handle your query results, but here's some Code Igniter-like pseudo-code provided for concreteness. You can adapt it to whatever your situation calls for:

```
foreach($query->result() as $row) {
    if ($row->media_type == 'photo') {
        $featured_photos[$row->item_name] = $row;
    }
    else {
        $featured_videos[$row->item_name] = $row;
    }
}
```

That example is a little silly because it just undoes the work of the union in your query, but the point is that once you get your results back you can use the media_type field to differentiate where the items came from.

Comment: Yes. But could you improve your answer to be more demonstrative / obvious for further readers?

Comment: So would I echo that out something like this? $row['photo.item_name']

Comment: I added more explanation - please let me know if that was helpful or if more context would be beneficial. The main thing is you have an object (or array) now with three fields: item_name, date_display, and media_type.

Comment: Should I have not used a UNION at all if I'm just trying to gather all items from each table where is_featured = yes? Is there a better way?

Comment: @mrtonyb You should use `UNION` in this case. It is better, that 3 separate queries. Faster and less memory consuming, at least.

Comment: I was able to figure it out with your suggestion. Very much appreciated.